# How to change selected menu option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using jquery chosen plugin. I want to selected menu value by selected value from other select menu. But my code working with simple selected menu. I want it to work with jquery chosen plugin. Example [code](http://jsfiddle.net/7vkLv/13/)

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen()
    $('[id*=second]').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val()

    if(val.toLowerCase()=='mr'){
    $('[id*=gender]').find('option').eq(0).attr('selected', 'selected');
}

else{       
    $('[id*=gender]').find('option').eq(1).attr('selected', 'selected')
     }
})
​
```

Comment: here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7vkLv/117/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7vkLv/100/)

I hope the below script does what you expect

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
$('[id*=second]').change(function(){
    var val = $('div[id*=second]').find('li.result-selected').html().trim();
    $('select[id*=gender]').find('option').removeAttr('selected');
    $('div[id*=gender]').find('li.active-result').removeClass('result-selected');
    var selectedValue = "";
    if(val.toLowerCase()=='mr'){
        selectedValue = $('div[id*=gender]').find('li.active-result').eq(0).addClass('result-selected').html();
        $('select[id*=gender]').find('option').eq(0).attr('selected','selected');
    } else {
        selectedValue = $('div[id*=gender]').find('li.active-result').eq(1).addClass('result-selected').html();
        $('select[id*=gender]').find('option').eq(1).attr('selected','selected');
    }
    $('div[id*=gender]').find('a.chzn-single span').html(selectedValue);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `value` to the options and try to match those value `onchange`. See my implementation below and let me know if it works for you.

**Edit:** Added few lines to update the plugin selection.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vUkQg/3/

> **Note:** Below method can relate any number of drop downs with just same class and `value`.(no change to the script) http://jsfiddle.net/vCE4Y/18/

**HTML:**

```
<select id="second" class="chzn-select" style="width:100px">
  <option value="1"> mr</option>
  <option value="2"> mrs</option>
</select>

<select id="gender" class="chzn-select" style="width:100px">
  <option value="1"> male</option>
  <option value="2"> female</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('.chzn-select').val(val);

        $('.chzn-select').not(this).each(function () {                       
            var $chzn = $('#' + this.id + '_chzn');
            var $li = $chzn.find('li');            
            $li.removeClass('result-selected');  

            var selectedLi = $li.eq(val - 1);
            selectedLi.addClass('result-selected');

            $chzn.find('a.chzn-single span').html(selectedLi.html());            
            //update selected result in plugin
            var $data = $(this).data('chosen');

            $.each($data['results_data'], function (idx, el) {
                if (idx == val-1) {
                    el.selected = true;
                    $data.result_single_selected = selectedLi;
                } else {
                    el.selected = false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: first select: "mrs" from first dropdown you then select: "male" from second dropdown then again click on first dropdown you will see "mrs" would be selected. i want to select male instead

Comment: @amit It is the plugin adding the class `highlight` when clicking the rendered dropdown. The same exist in the accepted demo.. I will try to work it around..

Comment: Now i just want to understand you use 'results_data' , 'selected' and $data.result_single_selected name in your function. what is that.

Comment: Those are the objects used by chosen plugin to maintain the selection.

Comment: is .data method used for access other function object

Answer (score 0):

Use **selectedIndex**

eg:

```
   document.getElementById('selectId').selectedIndex = 0; 

   //selectId - id of the select elem

<select id="selectId">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Male</option>
  <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

To get the Selected value

```
    var e = document.getElementById("selectId");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

here strUser = 1;

if you want the **TEXT**

```
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

here strUser = Male;

i think this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="second" class="chzn-select" style="width: 100px">
    <option value="1">mr</option>
    <option value="2">mrs</option>
</select>
<select id="gender" class="chzn-select" style="width: 100px">
    <option value="1">male</option>
    <option value="2">female</option>
</select>​

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.chzn-select').change(function () {
            $('.chzn-select').val($(this).val());
            //$('.chzn-select').val($(this).val()).trigger('change');
        });
    });​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/3UP3a/)

Comment: $('.chzn-select').val($(this).val()).trigger('change'); is required for IE and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I used the value of the options, the minus 1 is to reach the indexnumber

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vkLv/61/)

```
 $('#second').change(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();

    $('#gender option').eq(val - 1).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

or

```
$('#second').change(function(){
    var index = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;

    $('#gender option').eq(index).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```